# Webpack - include okaynav

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, webpack

I have a problem to get working this [demo](http://www.webpackbin.com/VyBK9aXtW). It has an error:

> Cannot resolve module 'okaynav/dist/js/jquery.okayNav-min'

How can I load [okayNav plugin](https://github.com/VPenkov/okayNav) and its css through Webpack?